# Is "you was" correct to say?

Tags: singular-vs-plural, colloquial-language, dialect

I've always learnt at school that we have to say: "You were + (add something)" either if the "you" is actually one person or more. But sometimes I heard or read "You was + (add something)" especially in some video games.

I remember that I saw it in a custom mod on Final Fantasy 7 on PC for example. But I've even heard some people say it, but those people were friendly between them.

I can't remember the sentence from FF7, but the words of the sentence were pretty much mashed. An example here though: "You was behind us the whole time". That sentence was said by a nice, yet random guy from an online game, I asked him if that was correct to say that, he said yes (but I wanted to confirm that).

So I was wondering if that is correct? Or is it a kind of a common -I would say- speaking mistake?

Answer (score 6):

There are many dialects in English. In some dialects, "you was..." is used.

Here is an example, the song "You was right, baby." ([YouTube](https://youtu.be/bOTLRpOAUnQ))

Lyrics:

> you said someday you’d turn the tide,
>   and i’d be laughin’ on the other side,
>   and **you was right, baby**,
>   baby, **you was so right**!
>
> you said someday the worm would turn,
>   i had some lessons that i had to learn,
>   and **you was right, baby**,
>   baby, **you was so right**!

([Metro Lyrics](http://metrolyrics.top/you-was-right-baby-lyrics-peggy-lee.html))

Your school teachers were probably teaching you the dialect called standard English, according to which *you was...* is not considered correct.

Comment: Oh I see... I will do some research about the dialects you mentioned. It's too bad that we weren't sensitized about that at school. Anyway, thank you for your answer :-)

Comment: It's a dialect, but it's also just plain wrong. You should never use this in formal speech or writing. Informally you can get away with it, but then, you can get away with a lot of things if you start talking about dialects. "You ain't using them words right" may be something you'd hear in a dialect, but it's still wrong (so very wrong).

Comment: @JamieB it's not "wrong"; it's merely non-standard. Different dialects of English are still perfectly valid constructions because they convey the necessary meaning. Look into AAE (African-American English) for more info, but any linguist worth their salt would tell you to leave opinionated prescriptivism out. Use "not standard" instead of "wrong" in the future, please.

Comment: you was wrong is wrong in standard English eventhough it is used in cerain dialects